# How to animate these transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm making a image slider and I have built the two functions that can switch to the next or previous picture. Now I just need to add some animations to them. How can I add animations to appendChild? If that's even possible

btw this is the array:
`[img.image1, img.image2, img.image3, img.image4]`

```
frame.appendChild(array[0])

console.log(array)

function next() {
  // remove current picture from frame
  pics.appendChild(array[0])
  array.push(array[0])

  // add new picture to frame
  frame.appendChild(array[1])
  array.shift();
  console.log(array);
}

function previous() {
  console.log(array)

 // removes current image from the frame
  pics.insertBefore(array[0], array[1])

  // adds new picture to the frame

  frame.appendChild(array[array.length -1])
  array.unshift(array[array.length - 1])
  array.pop();
}
```

Comment: "Now I just need to add some animations to them." Could you be a little more specific? What kind of animation? What have you tried?

Comment: right now it just instantly switches to the next image, i want the switch to be smoother. Im new to animations so I havent tried anything yet

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to add animation to your code. The reason is that you remove and add  element from from DOM. This action can't be animated.
You can refactor your code using CSS properties like: opacity, any positions (left, right, top bottom). Them are have certain values, that you can smooth increment with JS.
But things like display: block/none, isn't possible to animate